# How to use value of result when before select

Tags: sql-server

```
city    sex count
seoul   M   10
seoul   M   0
seoul   M   4
seoul   F   5
seoul   M   6
busan   M   6
busan   M   5
busan   F   5
busan   F   6
busan   M   7
```

I want change to

```
city    male    female  total
seoul   20      5       25
busan   18      11      29
```

I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CITY,
(SELECT SUM(count) FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = 'seoul' AND sex = 'M') AS male,
(SELECT SUM(count) FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = 'seoul' AND sex = 'F') AS female,
(SELECT SUM(count) FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = 'seoul') AS total
FROM TABLE
WHERE CITY = 'seoul'

SELECT DISTINCT 
CITY,
(SELECT SUM(count) FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = 'busan' AND sex = 'M') AS male,
(SELECT SUM(count) FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = 'busan' AND sex = 'F') AS female,
(SELECT SUM(count) FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = 'busan') AS total
FROM TABLE
WHERE CITY = 'busan'
```

but I don't know how many cities there are.

so I can't `WHERE city = ''` every time.

how to SELECT `WHERE CITY = CITY` ?

I want to like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CITY,
(SELECT SUM(count) FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = CITY AND sex = 'M') AS male,
(SELECT SUM(count) FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = CITY AND sex = 'F') AS female,
(SELECT SUM(count) FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = CITY) AS total
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track.  What you want to do here is to take conditional sums/counts:

```
SELECT
    CITY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'M' THEN count ELSE 0 END) AS male,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'F' THEN count ELSE 0 END) AS female,
    SUM(count) AS total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    CITY;
```

Comment: You should use `SUM` instead of  `Count` as the desired result of the OP.

Comment: @Phong You are right...I answered too quickly, +1 to your answer.

Comment: How about `COUNT(*) AS total` ?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `GROUP BY` instead of `Distinct` when you are working on the `aggregate` function.

```
SELECT CITY,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'M' THEN count ELSE 0 END)  AS male,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'F' THEN count ELSE 0 END)  AS female,
        SUM(count)  AS total
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CITY
```

Comment: You are missing the `total`, but other than that, this looks good +1.

Comment: And you have two `male` in the result